# .net, jax-ws, wsimport, svcUtil.exe

Tags: c#, java, enums, wsdl

Can anyone please tell how the enum values are mapped when we try to generate classes from wsdl in .net?

At provider end the web service language being used is java and generate the classes form wsdl using wsimport but the consumers consume this very service and based on the .net platform and use svcutil.exe to generate the classes. we can see that there is a mismatch in enum valuse being mapped from java to .net.

Please find the below piece of code for ref

```
using wsimport:
            <simpleType name="EnumContactCriteriaType">
        <restriction base="xsd:string">
            <enumeration value="PERSONAL" />
            <enumeration value="DEMOGRAPHIC" />
            <enumeration value="ADDLREGISDTLS" />
            <enumeration value="RECIPIENTDTLS" />
            <enumeration value="AUTHDTLS" />
            <enumeration value="REGISDTLS" />
         </restriction>
             </simpleType>

using svcutil:  
             <xs:simpleType name="EnumContactCriteriaType">
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="REGISDTLS" /> 
                    <xs:enumeration value="AUTHDTLS" /> 
                    <xs:enumeration value="RECIPIENTDTLS" /> 
                    <xs:enumeration value="ADDLREGISDTLS" /> 
                    <xs:enumeration value="DEMOGRAPHIC" /> 
                    <xs:enumeration value="PERSONAL" /> 
                   </xs:restriction>
             </xs:simpleType>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What mismatch? Are you referring to the order of the values?

Comment: yes the order of the values are displayed in reverse order

Comment: wsimport and svcutil generate code from the WSDL. There should be one XML schema in that WSDL but you are showing us two different pieces of XML schema. From where? Please make an effort to improve your question and better explain what your issue is.